# Passing functions to child components in React - this.props.handleChange is not a function?

Tags: reactjs

Trying to create a simple todo list and I figure out how to pass the function from the parent component down to the child component without it throwing an error

App Component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
  todo: todoData.map(todo => {
    return <TodoItem handleChange={this.handleChange} todo={todo} key={todo.id}  /> 
  }),
  count: 0,

  }
  handleChange = (id) =>  {
    console.log(id)
  }
  render(){
    return(
    <div className="flex">    
      <Header /> 
      <div className="todoList" > 
        {this.state.todo}  
      </div> 
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

TodoItem component

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component  {
    render(){ 
        console.log(this.props)
          return(
            <p className="todoItem"  onClick={this.props.clickeds}>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.todo.completed} onChange={() => this.props.handleChange(this.props.todo.id)} />
            {this.props.todo.text}
            </p>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm trying to mess with the onChange handler in the TodoItem component, but I keep getting the same error that this.props.handleChange is not a function

Todo just for reference

```
todoData = {
        id: 2,
        text: "Grocery Shopping",
       completed: false
    },
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I change the handleChange function to NOT an arrow function in the app component, it works. (handleChange(id)). If I  change this function to an arrow function (handleChange = (id) =>  { } ) I run into this error.

Comment: You're referencing it before it's defined. Arrow functions are instance properties; regular functions are part of the objects prototype.

Comment: Gotcha. So if I'm using arrow functions I need to define them at the top of the component? Moving the handleChange function above works as expected.

Comment: You need to define them before referencing them. But that's often a road to difficult-to-understand source code. It's also almost never necessary to put components into state; there's no reason to do it here AFAICT--this also avoid the problem in this case.

Comment: Thanks. still grasping these concepts

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use ES6's class syntax for now (which I have added below) as this is how most React tutorials —including the official ones— are written.

**The data structure you should keep in the state should be an Array of Todo Objects**.

You don't need to keep the components inside the state, simply iterate them on render (and don't worry about its performance, React won't recreate the HTML dom by doing this, so the render will be very efficient).

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      todos : todoData,
      count : 0,
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    const todos = this.state.todos.map(todo => (
      (todo.id === id)
      ? Object.assign(todo, { completed: !todo.completed }
      : todo
    ));

    this.setState({ todos });
  }

  render() {
    // ...
    this.state.todos.map(todo => (
      <TodoItem handleChange={this.handleChange} todo={todo} key={todo.id} />
    ); 
  }
}

// todoData should probably be an array in case you want to include more by default:
todoData = [
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Grocery Shopping",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Grocery Shopping",
    completed: false
  }
];
```

### Be careful about mutating the state

The reason for the ugly and confusing `map()` and `Object.assign()` inside `handleChange` is because you cannot do a shallow copy, nor edit the array directly:

```
this.state.todos[i].completed = true // ! mutates the state, no good
```

Preferably Lodash's library or even better, an immutable library or memoized selectors would do the trick of setting a todo as completed in a much nicer fashion.

Without deep cloning or immutability, you would need to copy the object, clone it, then create a new array with the new object, and assign that array to the state.

Comment: There's nothing intrinsically wrong with using instance properties.

Comment: I agree, but class properties are currently in stage 3 proposal, so not yet (but almost!) officially adopted.

Also, defining `handleChange = (id) =>` would recreate the arrow function for every class instance. I personally find `.bind` to not be such an inconvience to add once for every function.